# How to use numpy arange with pandas Series?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, series

I'm currently trying to calculate the new DataFrame column. It should equal the sum from 0 to the value of the existing column. For example, I have such DataFrame `df`:

```
   col1  
0     1
1     2
2     3
3     4
4     5
```

And now, I want to calculate the second column as a sum from 0 to the first column value.

```
   col1  col2
0     1     1
1     2     3
2     3     6
3     4    10
4     5    15
```

I tried this code

```
df['col2'] = np.arange(0,df['col1']+1,1).sum()
```

But get the error

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `df['col2'] = df['col1'].cumsum()`

Comment: I need sum from 0 to the col2 value

Comment: As an aside, your question was unnecessarily difficult to understand because you used a degenerate example input `[1,2,3,4,5]`, leading to an intuitive but wrong solution using `cumsum()`.  An example input like `[3, 5, 2]` would not have had this problem.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I see, I misunderstood the question, bad example indeed

Answer (score 2):

What you want is the sum of the first N positive integers.  That has a closed form solution: **N(N + 1)/2**.  The advantage of using such a solution is that you don't need to iterate over a sequence.

Using your example, the solution is:

```
df['col1'] * (df['col1'] + 1) // 2
```